# IE Anchor Link Jumps to Wrong Place

Tags: html, internet-explorer, anchor

I am building a long Client List page for a site. There are links on other pages that are to jump to a specific category of client (Industry). Everything's working great except for when testing in Internet Explorer.

I have a link with the following URL:

```
/about-us/client-list/#environment-conservationJump
```

On the Client List page, I have the following anchor:

```
<a id="environment-conservationJump">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
```

The first time I clicked on the link, it seemed to work, but now, after scrolling up and down the page a bit, if I refresh the page, it will jump to a different point in the page. Not always where another anchor exists, sometimes just part-way through one of the other lists.

In every other browser, everything is working great. I could just set the links to include a query string, and use jQuery to scroll down the page, but I'd prefer to not introduce another function to the page if I don't need to.

Has anyone run into this problem?

Comment: That doesn't help. IE is still, unforunately, widely used, so when developing a site, it needs to work for IE.

Comment: which IE version you have?

Comment: We are testing in the latest IE11, but when running IE11's emulation, older version experience the same issues.

Comment: Try adding the "name" attribute as well as the "ID"

Comment: I've tried it with just the ID, just the name, and with both, with the same results.

Comment: Is your anchor, or any element above it, positioned with CSS?

Comment: The anchor just sits right above an h3 tag that gives the category name. There are no styles applied to the anchor.

Comment: @Joe Can you provide a demo that we can access directly?